# Prosodic problem in U-Bahn announcement?

Tags: pronunciation, stress

I have recently started travelling by U-Bahn in a German city. Before each stop passengers are told:

> - Nächste Station Heddernheim. Ausstieg in **Fahrt** richtung links.
> - Nächste Station Dornbusch. Ausstieg in **Fahrt** richtung rechts.

The stress is on **Fahrt** and not on what I consider the salient feature of the announcement: whether I get off on the left or right. To my English ears the prosody sounds wrong. It should be:

> - Ausstieg in Fahrtrichtung **rechts**.

How does it sound to native German speakers?

Comment: Announcements at any public traffic carriers often just sound odd (and that's not only in germany).

Comment: Fahrtrichung is stressed on the first syllable. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: @fdb. The problem is not that _fahrt_ in _Fahrtrichtung_ is stressed. Clearly, this is correct. The problem is that the stress on it is greater than on any other syllable in the announcement. I, at least, would expect the most stressed syllable to be _links_ or _rechts_. Listen to the U6 announcement linked to by _mtwde_. The syllable _fahrt_ is stressed but has less prominence than _links_ or _rechts_ - for me the expected prosody. The U3 announcement is different.

Answer (score 2):

Fahrtrichtung is part of the direction where to get, left or right alone is not the only important thing. So a little emphasis on this word is ok to me.

But you are right, "Fahrt" is not the most important part. I know these announcements but I can't really follow your hearing from the announcements I know. Probably many public transport companies have different speakers that pronounce things slightly different. In case these are machine-spoken phrases (who knows?) there will be less details in emphasis. It would be interesting to get a sample of what is spoken.

Generally you are lucky if you just understood the announcement between all the noise in public transport :-)

Answer (score 2):

When recording announcements for train or subway stations you won't record the whole line. You will record reusable parts and put them together as needed.

"Nächste Station Heddernheim. Ausstieg in Fahrtrichtung links." would be split into

- Nächste Station
- Heddernheim
- Ausstieg in Fahrtrichtung
- links

Because of this these announcements sound mostly odd and not like spoken language. There are strange breaks and emphasises, but for my ears the salient features are always "links/rechts" and the name of the next station.

There is a YouTube-video from Frankfurt's S6 with all of its announcements. Maybe that helps: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgPQM5beoWA

Comment: Actually, the announcements I am referring to are clear and clearly spoken although made up of text fragments as you point out. And thanks for the link. The S6 speaker clearly stresses  the words _links_  and _rechts_. I consider this the normal prosody for such announcements. However, the speaker on the U3 stresses the part-word _Fahrt_. Hence my question.